# Celery Rate limit not working as expected in decorator in combination with rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I use

```
@app.task(rate_limit='5/s')
def add(x, y):
return x+y
```

and then i call in a second program:

```
for i in range(100):
    add.apply_async((i, i), queue='loci')
```

Then i start my celery but i see that it processes way less than the 5/s specified. It's more like 0.7-1 / second.

Why? I've read the documentation and from what i see there is that it should add a delay of 1/5 = 0.2 seconds to each call. I would expect it to finish after 20sec + overhead but instead it takes 1,5mins+

What am i doing wrong?